# Error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb, user-interface, jframe

I am trying to print my console output into jtextarea,but i am getting error while doing it.I am using Eclipse IDE.
Given Below **is part of** my code:

`enter code here

```
           JFrame frame4 = new JFrame("Showing full Transaction History");
           frame4.setBounds(100, 100, 677, 392);
           frame4.setVisible(true);
           frame4.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

            JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(20,20);

            JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(textarea);
            frame4.getContentPane().add(scrollPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            textarea.add(frame4);
            textarea.add(scrollPane1);
            textarea.setVisible(true);
            textarea.setEditable(false);
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself

Comment: You've provided a lot of code, but it's still incomplete and is almost certainly longer than it needs to be to demonstrate the problem. Please reduce to a [mcve].

Comment: Yeah you are right it's incomplete as i have provided only a part of my code.Actually the code is of onclicklistner of one of the buttons that i have used in my gui.My actual code is too big to post so posted only the part where i am getting error.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting posting your full code. I was suggesting that you post a minimal but still complete piece of code demonstrating the same problem. The task of coming up with that is part of the diagnostic work you should do before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add a JFrame to a text area.  It needs to be the other way around, e.g.

```
frame4.add(textarea);
```

And the same goes for your scrollpane.

This code assumes you're also going to give your JFrame some kind of layout which is pretty much always required.

Comment: I tried doing it you are saying like  `code((Container) frame4.getLayout()).add(textarea);
     ((Container) frame4.getLayout()).add(scrollPane1);` but i am getting different error this time it says this: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.awt.BorderLayout cannot be cast to java.awt.Container

Comment: I've edited my answer.  It was from memory and not tested. :)